# How can I move mail from one server to another?

Tags: email, postfix, dovecot

I currently host mail accounts on a VPS, which I want to move to a hosted CPanel account.

Mail is handled by Postfix and Dovecot, but I don't know much about the server I want to move the mail to.

How can I move the mail files to the new host?

As per John Siu's comments, there are five email accounts; I'm not sure what is meant by 'Linux accounts or virtual accounts'; I don't have access to all account passwords, but these can easily be reset; all accounts use IMAP.

Comment: Need more info to give suggestion.(1) How many accounts? (2) Linux account or virtual account? (3) You have access to all account password? (4) IMAP or POP3 only?

Comment: You have the system administrator do this for you. (Though a professional sysadmin might question your sanity for moving to a cPanel-based web host, that's another matter...)

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the solution:

Seeing that the Maildir on the old server houses files and directories that are pretty similar to the structure of folders on an email account, I compared against what would be in the directory for mail users on the new server: the same structure.

So, I set up new mail users on the new server, downloaded the Maildir directories for each user from the old server and then uploaded them to the new server via FTP, replacing whatever files and directories are put in place by default for the new users.

Checking the accounts via webmail shows that the emails and folders are readable straight away.